# Assigning multiple variables different values efficiently

Tags: python, sqlite, matplotlib, plotly

I'm trying to plot the number of times the strings "cappucino" and "americano" come up in my database onto a plotting graph. I'm trying to be more efficient and not have to write out a similar set of lines for each drink, when I add more. The solution works inefficiently. Any way to add different values to different variables efficiently? I get an error when i try to do e.g. for x in americano, cappucino: x = int(x[0]).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sqlite3

salesVolume = []
conn=sqlite3.connect("system.db")
cur=conn.cursor()
americano = cur.execute("""SELECT COUNT(id) FROM customerOrders WHERE product = 'Americano'""")
for x in americano:
    americano = int(x[0])
    salesVolume.append(americano)
cappucino = cur.execute("""SELECT COUNT(id) FROM customerOrders WHERE product = 'Cappucino'""")
for x in cappucino:
    cappucino = int(x[0])
    salesVolume.append(cappucino)
for x in americano, cappucino:
    americano, cappucino = int(x[0]), int(x[0])
    salesVolume.append(americano, cappucino)


plt.rcdefaults()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()


drinks = ('Americano','Cappucino','Latte','Espresso','Hot Chocolate', 'Mocha')
y_pos = np.arange(len(drinks))


ax.barh(y_pos, salesVolume, align='center')
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(drinks)
ax.invert_yaxis()  # labels read top-to-bottom
ax.set_xlabel('Sales Volume')
ax.set_title('Hot Drinks Sales Volume')

plt.show()

y=[10,20,30]
x=[15.30,45]
plt.bar(x,y,color='r',width='5')
plt.show
```

Comment: Load this into a `pandas.DataFrame` first.  Then with a `drinks` column you can do `df.groupby('drinks').plot()`

Comment: Could you please provide a reference for my learning? Thanks.

Comment: [pandas.read_spl](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html)